# Hyperlink not working on <input type=button

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Please see the below code.

I am using a search bar and added some buttons with it.

Only hyperlink of search button is working properly. But other buttons are not redirecting their link instead they are also redirecting to hyperlink of search button.

without search button other three buttons will use their added separate hyperlink. 
Can you please fix it?

See the codes

http://pastebin.com/uEJyyvsh

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section before posting - we need more information! Could you please post your code?

Comment: Hi, I added the codes at pastebin. Please see that

Comment: An `input` does not have an `href` attribute. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are keeping 4 submit button inside a form.
Search is the only submit button. Change rest of the button type to button only.

I) And, add `onlick="location.href='Your URL'"`. Like this,

```
<input type="button" style="background-color: red" value="Login" onclick="location.href='http://localhost/login/';">
```

II) Add , `onclick="javascript:window.open('http://www.facebook.com/', '_blank');">` for opening in new tab.

```
<input type="button" style="background-color: red" value="Facebook" onclick="javascript:window.open('http://www.facebook.com/', '_blank');">
```

1) `target="_blank"` is possible in anchor tag.

2) `formtarget="_blank"` is possible with submit button.

But, here no need of 4 submit button. For more info, check this [Submit Button Form Attribute - W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_formtarget.asp)

```
<div class="widget search_key" id="directory_search_location-5">
        <div class="widget-wrap widget-inside">
            <div class="search_nearby_widget what_fld_search">            
                <form style="position:relative;" action="http://localhost/wordpress/" id="searchform" class="searchform_5509 allinone" method="get" name="searchform_5509">
                    <input type="hidden" value="listing" name="post_type">
                    <input type="hidden" value="all" name="mkey[]">
                    <input type="text" size="100" placeholder="Looking For ..." class="searchpost placeholder" id="search_near-15100" name="s" value="" onkeypress="tmpl_insta_search_widget('searchform_5509')" onclick="tmpl_insta_search_widget('searchform_5509')">

                    <input type="hidden" value="a18247a9c8" name="t">
                    <input type="hidden" value="OR" class="sgo" name="relation">
                    <input type="submit" style="background-color: red" value="Search" onclick="tmpl_find_click(15100);" class="sgo">
                    <input type="button" style="background-color: red" value="Register" onclick="javascript:window.open('http://localhost/register/', '_blank');">
                    <input type="button" style="background-color: red" value="Login" onclick="javascript:window.open('http://localhost/login/', '_blank');">
                    <input type="button" style="background-color: red" value="Facebook" onclick="javascript:window.open('http://www.facebook.com/', '_blank');">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

If you really want to go to login,register, facebook page.. 
Give like this.

```
<a href="Your URL Here">
    <input type='button' value="Login">
</a>
```

Comment: Great, it's working. But it's breaking the line.  See screenshot: http://prntscr.com/8p2vv2 Please label all buttons in a same line, That's why I used all buttons in a form.. Also please add target="_blank" or formtarget="_blank". Awesome help. Looking forward to get a good copy.

Comment: Please try to label all buttons in a same line.

Comment: Is there any css written for submit button or simple button.? because, that code is nothing to do with CSS at all.. Trying to figure out the problem. meanwhile, you also search Mr @Strone

Comment: See, my edited answer. Which will work for you in opening in new tab. That layout problem is for CSS only.

Comment: Nope, I did not get any css for search button. I just added all other buttons with Search button. That's it.  Please see my submitted code.All buttons were same line there.

Comment: Sorry @Strone. That is now different question. Post that problem as different question. What i know is that my code will not affect any CSS code as it is not related to any CSS untill and unless any CSS file written for it.

Comment: Wow. it's opening in a new tab now. But the buttons are in not a same line. Thank you so much for quick and great help.

Comment: It feels good that anyone getting helped from my code.
Do not forget to tick it as correct answer. It will help other needy user to find it @Strone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the input button within an anchor tag. That should fix it.

Example.

```
<a href="http://localhost/register/" formtarget="_blank" ><input type="submit" style="background-color: red" value="Register"></a>
```

Comment: I edited the question. Please see again. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not working. Please try again. The issue is: Search button is working fine with hyperlink. But all other buttons also redirecting to the hyperlink of search button. I want, all other buttons should go their specific hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't have to use href to input,you should use 'a' tag.,there is no such attribute,but u can make input as link as like in below code,There is problem in your code,you have used one form multiple submit actions

```
<form action="http://google.com">
    <input type="submit" value="Go to Google">
</form>
```

or

```
<input type="submit" value="Go to my link location" 
    onclick="window.location='/my/link/location';" />
```

Comment: Hi, no luck. without 'Search' button all other buttons are still redirecting to the hyperlink of 'Search' button. They are not accepting their own hyperlink.

Comment: If I use several form then each button will display as in a new line below. I want all buttons will be same line with their own hyperlink.

Comment: use a tag instead of input

Answer (score 0):

you can use this type of code to link a page . you have to remove a tag

```
<input type="submit" value="Button Name" onclick="window.location.href='/pagename'">Continue</button>
```