# target blank with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I would like if you're on a submit button, click the page goes to another page and a new window opens with another page.

this is my html code

```
<div class="knop">
<form action="" method="post">
    <input target="blank" class="bal" type="submit" name="bal" value="">
</form>
```

and this is my php code

```
if(isset($_POST['bal'])){
header("Location: ping_pong_uitleg.php");//gaat naar de uitleg}
```

in the html put a link is not an option because it must be done with the submit button more things

I hope you can help me

Comment: You can't have it on the `input`, and it's `_blank`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't Use `target="_blank"` in submit button or any button. It's of no use. `target="_blank"` is used for anchor `<a></a>` tag

For submit button, use `formtarget="_blank"`

```
<div class="knop">
<form action="" method="post">
    <input class="bal" type="submit" formtarget="_blank" name="bal" value="">
</form>
```

For more info, Check my answer [Hyperlink not working on input type=button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33014996/hyperlink-not-working-on-input-type-button/33016213#33016213)

**For User's Requirement.**

Create one `id` for `submit` button i.e. `SubmitId` , use this `id` on `.click.` 
Basically, what it will do is : It will go to next page and meanwhile, it will change the `current Page (Ist Page) URL` too.

```
<form method='post' action="">
    <input type='text'>
    <input type='submit' id='SubmitId' formtarget="_blank">
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#SubmitId").click(function(){
         window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/";
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: The page has come in now are doing but how can I also change the current page

Comment: I didn't get you @William

Comment: Ok Ok. But, tell me one thing. If I'm in Page1 and after submitting Page1, I'm going to Page2. So, you want to change Page1 also. Is It @William ? Please be quick.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please have a look Mr @William.

Comment: @William : You have not responded about my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the `target` attribute can't be used on `input` elements.

What you are tying to do won't work the way you want it to, because the data is being sent to the server and then the page in redirecting (within the same window). To do what you want you will have to use JavaScript.

To open a window in a new tab with JavaScript you can do the following.

```
window.open('https://www.google.com/', '_blank');
```

This will submit your form and in the same instance open a new window with the URL you pass to the `window.open` method.

Here is a [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Ljr7emL9/1/) of the form submitting and opening in a new window.

Comment: Now I have not much experience with js so my question is how I should call code.

Comment: @William English please.

Comment: I changed it, I hope you can help me now.

Comment: But where you can adjust the link of the current window?

Comment: See @Nana Partykar's [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34418282/target-blank-with-php/34418456?noredirect=1#answer-34418743)

Answer (score 0):

Here's your solution:

```
<form action="" method="post" target="_blank">
  <input class="bal" type="submit" name="bal" value="">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want 2 things:

1. > click the page goes to another page

Submit the form in a new window. Add `formtarget="_blank"` to the `input`

```
<input class="bal" type="submit" formtarget="_blank" name="bal" value="">
```

2. > new window opens with another page

Put the url to your PHP file in the `action` attribute

```
<form action="/filename.php" method="post">
```